# Pass a flag from one event to another in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a Text Input field in a form with id say "input_id". During loading the page I would populate the field with existing data

While submitting the form using a button of id "form_submit", I want to determine if the field has been altered in any way. So that I would take particular action pertaining to the change.

```
In Jquery:

$("#input_id").on("keyup",function(){
    //set a flag to indicate the field is altered
})

$("#form_submit").on("click",function(){
    //check flag to see if #input_id is changed
}
```

So how do I set a flag in one event, and read it in another without using a global variable ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: I want to set a flag in one event, and read it at another event. How do I do that

Comment: You don't need to pass anything around, if you just go for the simple option of comparing the current value with the `defaultValue` property. (Be aware, that is a property of the HTML element object, not of the jQuery object - so you'll have to de-reference it before accessing that property, `$("#input_id")[0].defaultValue`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.data()` for this purpose,

```
var submit = $("#form_submit");

$("#input_id").on("keyup",function(){
 submit.data("changed",true);
});

submit.on("click",function(){
   if($(this).data("changed")){ //do something }
}
```

Comment: @BarathBushan Glad to help! :)

Comment: `I want to determine if the field has been altered in any way`, what if a user do some change after that rollback the changes then this trick will prove to be wrong.

Comment: In my scenario, just flagging an attempted edit would suffice

Comment: @BarathBushan...then plz do some edits in the question.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla, Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use the form data attribute:

```
$("#input_id").on("keyup",function(){
    //set a flag to indicate the field is altered
    $(this).closest('form').data('changed',true);
})

$("#form_submit").on("click",function(){
    //check flag to see if #input_id is changed
    console.log($(this).closest('form').data('changed'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for demonstrating the "closest" function

Answer (score 3):

So why not just an upper scope flag?

```
var flag = false;
$("#input_id").on("keyup",function(){
  // check stuff ...
  flag = true;
});

$("#form_submit").on("click",function(){
  if (flag) {

  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: I considered this option. But I did not want to use global variables